# Why member field 'table' in 'java.util.HashMap' is transient?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I learnt, the `transient` keyword prevents the **values** of instance fields that are declared with `transient` keyword from being persisted when an object is serialized.

Below is the code from `java.util.HashMap`:

```
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
    implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable {

             ....
             static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {...}
             transient Node<K,V>[] table;
}
```

Why values of instance field `table` are not part of serialization? Because values of `table` field is the actual content of `class HashMap` instance from implementation perspective.

*Note: [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/Serialization/TransientKeywordDemo.java) is one exercise on using transient keyword.*

Comment: Basically, when the class member in question is unnecessary to reconstruct the object from its serialized form...

Comment: What @fge said. Object caches, injected services, cached / lazily computed values, ...

Comment: @fge But `Node<K,V>[] table;` field in above query is required to create an instance of `HashMap` because `table` is an instance member of `public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
    implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable{..}`?

Comment: Serialization and the constructor are two entirely separate matters. TL;DR, but try and see whether HashMap has implementations of the .readResolve() and .writeReplace() methods, the answer probably lies in there.

Comment: Because it's reconstuctable, and because it's sparse, so serializing it would be wasteful of bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does one decide to not serialize a member by giving transient
>   modifier?

1. When the field refers to a resource that doesn't make sense to be serialised. For example, a OutputStream or a Window handle.
2. When the field can be reconstructed from the other information that is serialised. This helps in reducing the amount of data that need to be written.

> For example, why member field table is not part of serialization?

Because (2). Have a look at the `readObject` method in the `HashMap` class. The `table` field is reconstructed using the other information in the class.

Comment: My upvote for this answer, I could not upvote, because I down voted before. Sorry!!!

Answer (score 0):

An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created.

Since the 'table', in the example you mentioned, gets constructed with other 2 params and used by this data structure for representation, one need not bother about its serialization.

E.g. you could see it below :

```
   public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        if (initialCapacity < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal initial capacity: " +
                                               initialCapacity);
        if (initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
            initialCapacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
        if (loadFactor <= 0 || Float.isNaN(loadFactor))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal load factor: " +
                                               loadFactor);

        // Find a power of 2 >= initialCapacity
        int capacity = 1;
        while (capacity < initialCapacity)
            capacity <<= 1;

        this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
        threshold = (int)(capacity * loadFactor);
        table = new Entry[capacity];
        init();
    }
```

Comment: gets created post de-serialisation? no constructor is invoked when the object is reconstituted(de-serialisation)

Answer (score 0):

Because `Node<K, V>[] table` is sparse, it is a waste of time to serialize all this array. Instead, we only need to serialize the non-empty elements in the array which is enough to reconstruct the table later.

```
    void internalWriteEntries(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        Node<K,V>[] tab;
        if (size > 0 && (tab = table) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {
                for (Node<K,V> e = tab[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
                    s.writeObject(e.key);
                    s.writeObject(e.value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```